# Android studio/Intellij Idea: live template equivalent for choosen methods proposal

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

For `Toast`, there's a live template (callable by CTRL+J) wich create this line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "mytext", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Where `MyClass.this` and `"mytext"` are easily editable by typing Enter (it's the principle of LiveTemplates in Android Studio/Intellij IDEA).

Is there similar shortcut that "transform" methods proposition into "live templates" ? For example, if i choose the second signature of `append`:

[image: Method list for <code>append</code>]

is it possible to get the same mechanism of live template for quickly typing parameters ?

Comment: Afaik, that's not possible. However, try `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Space` (Smart completion) within the brackets. This will suggest all applicable parameters. If there is only one suggestion, it will insert it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i've found a keyboard shortcut that is approaching : Ctrl + P : show the parameters (and bold the current one).

[image]